# Dynamically Updating Website Over Time

Tags: javascript, dynamic, auto-update

I am wondering if someone could give me a brief explanation as to how a site like [darebee.com](http://darebee.com/) can auto-update its content every day.  I understand javascript can be used to create div content through use of arrays but I don't think that is what is going on here.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) Do you mean persistent changes that are saved permanently unless deleted? If so, then you need some kind of database/xml system.

Comment: Daily changes are often made on the server end not the browser end otherwise anyone could see what was on there tomorrow or yesterday if they know where to look. Your question would be better posed under like php nodejs maybe even sql. Things that run on the server end. If you're looking for user specific changes then that would be dealing with JavaScript and cookies.